# How do I change the position of the button after initialization?

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I have `ASViewController<ASDisplayNode>`. In `init()` I set into display node new node with `ASAbsoluteLayoutSpec` which contains two button. How I can change button position during `ASViewController` lifecycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of cause, you can. Just use the variable `flag` or `switch` statement in `layoutThatFits:` method for change logic behavior, and after changing a `flag` state call just `self.setNeedsLayout` or `transitionLayoutWithAnimation:shouldMeasureAsync:measurementCompletion:` for animation, and this recommended method for change layouts.
For more info read the [docs](http://texturegroup.org/docs/layout-transition-api.html)
Example:

```
override func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {
let fieldNode: FieldNode

  if self.fieldState == .signupNodeName { // flag dependens state
      fieldNode = self.nameField
  } else {
      fieldNode = self.ageField
  }

  let stack = ASStackLayoutSpec()
  stack.children = [fieldNode, buttonNode]

  let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)
  return ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: insets, child: stack)
}
```

for change layouts use `transitionLayoutWithAnimation:shouldMeasureAsync:measurementCompletion:` method call. Don't forget change a state before of this call.

Comment: Can you please tell me when layoutSpecThatFits gets called?

Comment: Most often by `[ASViewController loadView]()` but it depends on the situation. A better way to understand it going to GitHub sources, or by debug.